# Uploading photo without changing its original size does not function

Tags: php, upload, photo

```
$resizeObj = new resize($routePath.$imgPathLease.$photosrc);

$resizeObj->resizeImage(1024, 768, 'auto');
$resizeObj->saveImage($routePath.$imgPathLease.'detail-'.$leaseid.'-'.$uploadnum.'-'.$photosrc, 80);

$detailImg = $leaseid.'-'.$uploadnum.'-'.$photosrc;
$mcProperty->InsertLeasePhoto($db, $leaseid, $detailImg);

$resizeObj->resizeImage(300, 300, 'crop');
$resizeObj->saveImage($routePath.$imgPathLease.'thumb-'.$leaseid.'-'.$uploadnum.'-'.$photosrc, 80);
```

Basically the code above functions as am upload for a larger image and a cropped our 300x300 thumbnail version of itself.

What I want is the first upload will follow through without any resizing.

My issue is that if I take out

> **$resizeObj->resizeImage(1024, 768, 'auto');**

, the larger image does not upload. So im assuming I will just keep that line for this function to work.

Also, the photo name is what i am aiming for thats why the saveImage code exists.

Is there any code that can go like this?:

> $resizeObj->resizeImage("width=100%", "width=100%", 'auto');

Thanks

Comment: If you dont want to change the shape or size of the uploaded image, then just dont run ANY of this code on the image. Simples

Comment: the photo name is what i am aiming for thats why the saveImage code exists

Comment: Look up [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) in the PHP Manual. Thats all you have to do to the image if you dont want to chnage it in any way

Comment: Here is another [useful page in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Why you use resizeImage(); ?

Answer (score 0):

first check the size of photo you are uploading , and also check $_Files array to check whether there is any error in $_Files['error'].

If yes then you need to increase max_upload limit in PHP.ini file or simple by using ini_set() function in php.

And then try if your uploading is complete or not.If still there is a problem then please provide the logs for the same.